# TomEE, rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-tomee

I am working on developing an interface between TomEE application server and rabbitmq. 
Is there any example that can show me what is to be configured in the tomEE server ?
How can I initiate tomEE to create a exchange and queue and than send out messages ?

Answer (score 1):

not sure I fully got the question bu you can embed java client in your application and use Java API: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

If you want to use JMS you can rely on https://github.com/imatix/openamq-jms but since there is no rabbitmq resource adapter it is still "manual".